# Multidimensional array initialization

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am currently recreating a graph class that can display an adjacency matrix and find its respective DFS and BFS. While looking at reference code they used the following code to generate a multidimensional array.

I was under the assumption that the only way to make a multi dimensional array was:
data_type  array_name[size1][size2]....[sizeN];

Is the pointer at the initialization setting up a multidimensional array such that each element in "array 1" contains another array "array 2?" Is this a dynamic array? And what would be their purpose for using this instead of initializing it the other way?

Code Mentioned:

```
            adjmatrix = new int*[vertexCount];
            for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++){
                adjmatrix[i] = new int[vertexCount];
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the assumption that the only way to make a multi dimensional array was: data_type array_name[size1][size2]....[sizeN];

Your assumption was and is correct.

> Is the pointer at the initialization setting up a multidimensional array such that each element in "array 1" contains another array "array 2?"

No.

Each element in "array 1" contains a **pointer that points** to another "array 2".

> Is this a dynamic array?

Yes. `new` creates dynamic objects.

> And what would be their purpose for using this instead of initializing it the other way?

We are not them, so we cannot know.

But, the other way doesn't allocate dynamically. Furthermore, the dimensions of array variables are compile time constant. The size of dynamic arrays is dynamic at runtime. These may have influenced their choice.